# Viewmodel owner en navigation components android

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de agrupar una serie de `fragments` usando `NestedGraph`, lo que quisiera saber es como puedo asignar a dicho grupo un `viewmodel` específico, sin que su `owner` sea el `activity` padre, probé usando `parentFragment`. pero es asignado el `navhostfragment`, mas no una referencia que englobe a todo el conjunto.

siguiendo este este ejemplo:

```
MainActivity
|- MainNavHost
   |- NavBarFragment
   |  |- NestedNavHost
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment1
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment2
   |  |
   |  |- BottomNavigationView
   |
   |- LoginFragment
```

De acuerdo al ejemplo, me gustaría que `navBarFragment` tenga su propio `viewmodel` con su propio `owner`, en ese caso puede ser el `MainActivity`, pero en caso de `NestedNavHost` si debería manejar su propio `lifecycleowner`.

Aquí una referencia de [NestedGraphs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs):